# Cypress CI integration with GitHub

Tags: automation, cypress

Can someone help if I understand why I can't connect cypress with Github? I get this 422 error message whenever I request access to connect cypress to Github.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for the above 422 error(permission error) that you get while accessing github from cypress:

1. you do not have access to the github repo you are trying to access, check with your Github admin
2. if you have  a particular Team(Dev/QA/DevOps/PM etc) access to github account of your org, check with your Github admin to see if above repository has been added to your Team for access.